# Unable to read from JTextArea and write to file

Tags: java, swing, io, jtextarea, bufferedwriter

i have a class which reads from a text file and writes the contents to a JTextArea. This works fine, however im unable to write the contents of the pane back to a different text file. The purpose is so that other contents can be written by hand into the text area, then save to a file if needs be. I have a button but it doesnt seem to be doing anything when clicked. Any advice would be great.

please note, the code contains three panes (cards). I am only using card1 at the moment.

Thanks

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MobileHome extends JFrame implements ActionListener {






 final String card1Text = "Card 1";
 final String card2Text = "Card 2";
 final String card3Text = "Card 3";
 final JPanel cards; //a panel that uses CardLayout
 // button commands
 final String FIRST = "FIRST";
 final String NEXT = "NEXT";
 final String PREVIOUS = "PREVIOUS";
 final String LAST = "LAST";


 File file = new File("mobOne.txt");
 BufferedReader reader  = null;
 public String read()
 {
    String savetext = "";

 try{
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String text = null;


    while((text = reader.readLine()) != null){


        final String LS = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        savetext += text + LS;  

        }

    }
 catch(IOException jim){
    jim.printStackTrace();
 }
 return savetext;
 }


 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());
     String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
     if (cmd.equals(FIRST)) {
         cl.first(cards);
     } else if (cmd.equals(NEXT)) {
         cl.next(cards);
     } else if (cmd.equals(PREVIOUS)) {
         cl.previous(cards);
     } else if (cmd.equals(LAST)) {
         cl.last(cards);
     }
 }
 JButton saveOne = new JButton("Save to file");

 JTextArea mobOneText = new JTextArea("TextField on Card 1", 15, 20);




public MobileHome() {



    super("Mobile Wizard");

    //Create the "cards".
    JPanel card1 = new JPanel();

    saveOne.addActionListener(this);
    card1.add(saveOne);

    card1.add(mobOneText);
    mobOneText.setText(read());




    card1.setBackground(new Color(255,0,0));




    JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
    card2.add(new JTextField("TextField on Card 2", 20));
    card2.setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));

    JPanel card3 = new JPanel();
    card3.add(new JLabel("Card 3"));
    card3.setBackground(new Color(0,0,255));

    //Create the panel that contains the "cards".
    cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
    cards.add(card1, card1Text);
    cards.add(card2, card2Text);
    cards.add(card3, card3Text);






    JButton btn1 = new JButton("First");
    btn1.setActionCommand(FIRST);
    btn1.addActionListener(this);

    JButton btn2 = new JButton("Next");
    btn2.setActionCommand(NEXT);
    btn2.addActionListener(this);

    JButton btn3 = new JButton("Previous");
    btn3.setActionCommand(PREVIOUS);
    btn3.addActionListener(this);

    JButton btn4 = new JButton("Last");
    btn4.setActionCommand(LAST);
    btn4.addActionListener(this);

    JPanel controlButtons = new JPanel();
    controlButtons.add(btn1);
    controlButtons.add(btn2);
    controlButtons.add(btn3);
    controlButtons.add(btn4);

    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("hand.jpg");
    setIconImage(img.getImage());

    Container pane = this.getContentPane();
    pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    pane.add(controlButtons, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);



    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300, 200);
    setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent f) {


    if (f.getSource().equals(saveOne)) {
        try {
            BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename.txt")); 
            String myString1 =mobOneText.getText();
            String myString2 = mobOneText.getText();

            System.out.println(myString2);

            fileOut.write(myString1);
            fileOut.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your saveOne probably **is** working fine, but I'll bet that you're not looking in the right place for the file. Have you looked in the user's directory? You can do a println to see what the `file.getAbsolutePath()` returns to find your file, you know.

Comment: Do you get any error messages?

Comment: Use [`JTextComponent.write(Writer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%290) instead.

Comment: Hi, not to sure where to start for that. I have tried changing  the code within but still dont seem to be getting anywhere using JTextcomponent. Any example would be much appreciated. Not looking for someone to write it for me, but seem to be going in circle. Thanks for the replies

Comment: Have you looked for the file yet?? If you're not getting an error, you have a file to find.

Comment: hey, searched, browsed, but no sign of it.

Comment: Have you printed out the absolute path?

Comment: do you mean a full path for the file? I have tried "C:\\Users\\Jimbob\\Desktop\\eclipse\\filename.txt"
but still not showing up :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actionPerformed1(ActionEvent f) there is no method defined in ActionListener. here is your fixed code.

```
 package javaapplication7;

 /**
  *
  * @author imran
  */
 import java.awt.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.BufferedWriter;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileReader;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;

 import javax.swing.*;
 class MobileHome extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


 final String card1Text = "Card 1";
 final String card2Text = "Card 2";
 final String card3Text = "Card 3";
 final JPanel cards; //a panel that uses CardLayout
 // button commands
 final String FIRST = "FIRST";
 final String NEXT = "NEXT";
 final String PREVIOUS = "PREVIOUS";
 final String LAST = "LAST";


  File file = new   File("C:/Users/imran/Desktop/JavaApplication7/src/javaapplication7/mobile.txt");
 BufferedReader reader  = null;
 public String read()
{
String savetext = "";

try{
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
String text = null;


while((text = reader.readLine()) != null){


    final String LS = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    savetext += text + LS;  

    }

}
 catch(IOException jim){
jim.printStackTrace();
 }
 return savetext;
}


/*public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
 CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());
 String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
 if (cmd.equals(FIRST)) {
     cl.first(cards);
 } else if (cmd.equals(NEXT)) {
     cl.next(cards);
 } else if (cmd.equals(PREVIOUS)) {
     cl.previous(cards);
 } else if (cmd.equals(LAST)) {
     cl.last(cards);
 }
 }*/
 JButton saveOne = new JButton("Save to file");

 JTextArea mobOneText = new JTextArea("TextField on Card 1", 15, 20);




  public MobileHome() {



   super("Mobile Wizard");

  //Create the "cards".
   JPanel card1 = new JPanel();

   card1.add(saveOne);
   saveOne.addActionListener(this);

   card1.add(mobOneText);
   mobOneText.setText(read());




card1.setBackground(new Color(255,0,0));




   JPanel card2 = new JPanel();
   card2.add(new JTextField("TextField on Card 2", 20));
   card2.setBackground(new Color(0,255,0));

   JPanel card3 = new JPanel();
   card3.add(new JLabel("Card 3"));
   card3.setBackground(new Color(0,0,255));

   //Create the panel that contains the "cards".
   cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());
   cards.add(card1, card1Text);
   cards.add(card2, card2Text);
   cards.add(card3, card3Text);






JButton btn1 = new JButton("First");
btn1.setActionCommand(FIRST);
btn1.addActionListener(this);

JButton btn2 = new JButton("Next");
btn2.setActionCommand(NEXT);
btn2.addActionListener(this);

JButton btn3 = new JButton("Previous");
btn3.setActionCommand(PREVIOUS);
btn3.addActionListener(this);

JButton btn4 = new JButton("Last");
btn4.setActionCommand(LAST);
btn4.addActionListener(this);

JPanel controlButtons = new JPanel();
controlButtons.add(btn1);
controlButtons.add(btn2);
controlButtons.add(btn3);
controlButtons.add(btn4);

ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("hand.jpg");
setIconImage(img.getImage());

Container pane = this.getContentPane();
pane.add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
pane.add(controlButtons, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);



setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
setSize(300, 200);
setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent f) {

 System.out.println("hi");
  CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());
 String cmd = f.getActionCommand();
 if (cmd.equals(FIRST)) {
     cl.first(cards);
 } else if (cmd.equals(NEXT)) {
     cl.next(cards);
 } else if (cmd.equals(PREVIOUS)) {
     cl.previous(cards);
 } else if (cmd.equals(LAST)) {
     cl.last(cards);
 }
if (f.getSource().equals(saveOne)) {
    try {
        System.out.println("hello");
        BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("filename.txt")); 
        String myString1 =mobOneText.getText();
        String myString2 = mobOneText.getText();

        System.out.println(myString2);

        fileOut.write(myString1);
        fileOut.close();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     new MobileHome();
 }
}
```

I have just removed the actionPerformed1(ActionEvent f) from your code and copied all the content of this method in actionPerformed(ActionEvent e).